# system.log flooded with xpcproxy errors during sleep time. How do I diagnose?

Tags: sleep-wake, catalina, logs, console

A few weeks ago my Macbook Pro 2018 with Catalina 10.15.2 started to get mad during sleep-time, actually it's not really going to sleep as it's flooding the system.log with hundreds of these lines:

```
Jan 28 14:11:37 MecBucPro-2 xpcproxy[35888]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 28 14:11:37 MecBucPro-2 xpcproxy[35889]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Jan 28 14:11:37 MecBucPro-2 xpcproxy[35890]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

I'm pretty sure it could be a driver, maybe the Wacom tablet driver which was updated recently, but I am not sure.

The only thing I'm sure is the Macbook is sleeping fine when disconnected from everything, while connected to display+hub+dock goes crazy.

Any further ways to diagnose this?

The number in brackets "xpcproxy[XXXXXXX]" is a process ID? In this case how to investigate this process as there are thousands in sequence??

Answer (score 2):

Further investigation: wake-up loop was due to a bad USB hub chain which probably makes Catalina go mad (but worked with Mojave). Reconnected 2 hubs and a Thunderbolt dock in a different order and solved it.

Anyway the xpcproxy error is there at every wake-up but at least not in constant loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a bad experience. My MBP 2018 met the same problem. Every night I go to sleep and close my computer's screen, it doesn't sleep at all. I noticed that because this problem wasted at least 50% of the battery which was full when I closed the screen. But I didn't connect any device to it.

The system log is that

```
xpcproxy[6453]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

This will repeat all the time. It seems that there is no resulution.